# Backward Stepwise Selection

Tags: regression

I need to implement a backward stepwise regression. I read the chapter from "The Elements of Statistical Learning" however the explanation is poor here:

> Backward-stepwise selection starts with the full model, and
>   sequentially deletes the predictor that has the least impact on the
>   fit. The candidate for dropping is the variable with the smallest
>   Z-score
>   **This is taken from chapter 3.3.2 pg:59**

I need to know what is the "full model" mentioned here? What will I delete at each level acording to the Z-score? I need to know how this algorithm works step by step.

**EDIT:** I try to implement the code on matlab. I don't know I'm totally wrong or not :/ Comment on this function please

```
function [] = BackwardStepWise(X,y,N,p)  % X is Nxp matrice y is Nx1 matrice

X = [ones(N,1) X];

% vector for holding column numbers 
v= 1:p;

for k=p-1:-1:1

        %create matrix with the selected columns
        T= [ones(N,1)];
        for j=1:k
            %add column to the matrix
            T = [T X(:,v(1,j)+1)];
        endfor
        %evaluate beta
        beta = inv(T' * T) * T' * y;

    %calculate Z-scores for each column
    sigmahat_sq = (y-T*beta)'*(y-T*beta)/(N-p-1);
    TT = inv(T'*T);
        Zmin = 100000;
        Zminindex = -1;
    for i=1:size(beta,2)
        z(i) = beta(i)/sqrt(sigmahat_sq*TT(i,i));
                if(z(i) < Zmin)
            Zmin = z(i);
            Zminindex = i;
        endif
    endfor

    %drop column which has the smallest Z score (edit v vector)
    v2 = [];
    for i=1:size(v,2)
        if(i == Zminindex)
            continue;
        else
        v2 = [v2 v(i)]; 
        endif       
    endfor  
    v = v2;

endfor

endfunction
```

Comment: The full model holds all possible independent variables (predictors) candidates.

Comment: And at each step you'll delete a variable.

Comment: There is no context or page number for this quotation but it seems a model of concise explanation to me!

Comment: @NickCox I edited the post adding chapter and page number

Comment: Thanks; this is widely known and used book; nevertheless naming authors, publisher and date would do no harm.

Comment: [Matlab has existing code for stepwise regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwisefit.html) although not explicit about which direction it uses.

Comment: @AdamO : If you click "Algorithms" it describes the procedure; it depends on how you initiate your model.

Comment: Also, please think about whether you "need to implement a backward stepwise regression." When predictors are inter-correlated, stepwise regression can lead to models that don't generalize well to new samples.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up an exit criterion for the p-value. Any independent variable with a p-value higher than this criterion will be removed. There isn't any golden rule on what to set, for exploratory purpose you may see p > 0.2 being removed. Someone may used 0.05, etc.
2. Set up your full model. Generally, it's the model that contains all independent variables from which you wish to select the predictive bunch.
3. Fit the full model.
4. Check the p-values (or t-statistics). If all p-values are less than the exit criterion, then it's the final model. If any of them exceeds the exit criterion, then the one with the highest p-value (aka lowest t-statistics) will be removed. This is pertinent to your "dropping the variable with the smallest z-score."
5. Fit the model with the remaining independent variables again, repeat steps 4 and 5 until either no independent variable is left or no independent variable has a p-value larger than the exit criterion.

Here is an example using Stata:

```
. sysuse auto
. stepwise, pr(.2): reg mpg weight turn headroom foreign price
                      begin with full model
p = 0.9238 >= 0.2000  removing price
p = 0.7047 >= 0.2000  removing headroom
p = 0.2045 >= 0.2000  removing turn

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  2,    71) =   69.75
       Model |   1619.2877     2  809.643849           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  824.171761    71   11.608053           R-squared     =  0.6627
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.6532
       Total |  2443.45946    73  33.4720474           Root MSE      =  3.4071

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0065879   .0006371   -10.34   0.000    -.0078583   -.0053175
     foreign |  -1.650029   1.075994    -1.53   0.130      -3.7955    .4954422
       _cons |    41.6797   2.165547    19.25   0.000     37.36172    45.99768
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The independent variables are `weight`, `turn`, `headroom`, `foreign`, and `price`. The dependent variable is `mpg`. The exit criterion is p > 0.2. The first got removed was `price` (p = 0.9238), followed by `headroom` (p = 0.7047) and `turn` (p = 0.2045). The remaining ones have p < 0.2, so they stay.

Comment: I tried to implement that function. But I didn't understand your first step. :/ Could you check my code?(I edited the question)

Comment: @CagkanToptas, I don't use MATLAB so probably can't give you useful feedback in a timely manner. MATLAB does have a [stepwise regression module](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwisefit.html), perhaps you can find out if they provide the source code?

Comment: @CagkanToptas: you can find the MATLAB code for `stepwisefit.m` under `toolbox/stats/stats/stepwisefit.m`. It is "standard" MATLAB code so it shouldn't be hard to read.